# Conjectures regarding EM approximations of mixtures of multivariate normal distributions

Tags: maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, expectation-maximization, bic, bounds

Consider $X\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times d}$ containing data for $N$ points in $d$ dimensions drawn from a bimodal multivariate normal distribution, where any row $x$ of $X$ follows the mixed multivariate normal distribution
$$X \sim P\big(x|(a_1,\mu_1,\Sigma_1),(a_2,\mu_2,\Sigma_2)\big) = a_1N_1(x|\mu_1,\Sigma_1)+ a_2 N_2(x|\mu_2,\Sigma_2)$$
where $0\lt a_1,a_2\lt 1, a1+a2=1$ and $x,\mu_1,\mu_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and $ \Sigma_1, \Sigma_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}.$ The matrix $X$ can be constructed by following the two step process: 1) choose a set of random class assignments $z=\{z_1,\dots,z_N\}$ where each $z_i \in \{1,2\}$ is assigned at random from a Bernoulli distribution with $p=a_1$ indicating the probability of assignment to class 1, and 2) for each $z_i$ instantiate the random $x$ from the multivariate normal $N_{z_i}$.

Conjecture:
$$
-\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|z_i,a,\mu,\Sigma) 
\le -\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|\hat{z}^{(2)}_i,a,\mu,\Sigma) 
\le -\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|\hat{\mu},\hat{\Sigma}) 
$$

where $a,\mu,\Sigma$ indicate the list of values for both classes, e.g., $a=\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\hat{z}^{(2)}$ is any assignment from a convergent Expectation-Maximization algorithm with $(2)$ centers. The upper bound is the one-component multivariate based on the sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ and sample covariance $\hat{\Sigma}$. In other words, EM establishes an upper bound for the value of the log-likelihood of the initially defined dataset, in which all $z_i$ class assignments are specified. Are there any cases when the EM algorithm is *better* (has lower negative log-likelihood) than the fully-specified case?

Question: Does this conjecture exist as a theorem?

Additional conjecture:

$$
BIC (X|z,a,\mu,\Sigma) 
\le BIC^{(2)} (X|\hat{z}^{(2)},a,\mu,\Sigma)
\le BIC^{(k\ne 2)} (X|\hat{z}^{(k\ne2)},a,\mu,\Sigma),
$$

where BIC is the Bayesian Information Criterion.

These seems like they might be theorems. (I'll cop to some wishful thinking, here, so I am at risk to being willfully blind to obvious counterexamples.)

Comment: Yes, these parameters are definite and hard-coded in my simulations. My interest is to prove that a convergent EM algorithm can be trusted to be worse than the actual. Perhaps I should say "almost surely worse than the actual."

Comment: Thank you. I will search for some examples of this and will re-strategize appropriately.

Comment: The following Statistical Science paper is of potential help: [Wu & Lange (2010)](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1300108233)

Answer (score 1):

Some arguments why the inequality
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|z_i,\mu,\Sigma) 
\ge \sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|\hat{z}_i,\mu,\Sigma) 
\ge \sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|\hat a,\hat{\mu},\hat{\Sigma})$$
does not always hold:

1. the first term is one realisation of the random variable $$\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|Z_i,\mu,\Sigma)$$and the expectation of $$P(x_i|Z_i,\mu,\Sigma)$$ in $Z_i$ (unconditional on $X_i$) is $$P(x_i|a,\mu,\Sigma)$$Hence it is sometimes smaller and sometimes larger than $$\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|a,\mu,\Sigma)$$
2. the third term$$\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|\hat{\mu},\hat{\Sigma})$$is the log-likelihood at the MLE (assuming EM has converged to the global mode). Hence
   $$\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|\hat{\mu},\hat{\Sigma})\ge\sum_{i=1}^N\log P(x_i|a,{\mu},{\Sigma})$$
   even though $(a,{\mu},{\Sigma})$ is the true parameter behind the sample of the $x_i$'s.
3. the EM algorithm increases the observed likelihood at each iteration, converging to the or a mode of the said likelihood but the computed $\hat z_i$'s are expectations,
   $$\hat z_i = \hat z_i(\hat a,\hat \mu, \hat \Sigma) =\mathbb E[Z_i|X_i,\hat a,\hat \mu, \hat \Sigma]$$
   not maximisers of the complete likelihood function. There is thus no argument for the complete likelihood to increase between EM iterations.